# Cannot import tensorflow- Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.x

I installed tensorflow using a virtual environment (code shown below):

```
conda create -n tf36 python=3.6
conda activate tf36
pip install tensorflow
```

This installs tensorflow 2.1.0

However, when I try 'import tensorflow as tf' in Python, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pavere\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\pavere\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\pavere\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\pavere\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\pavere\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\pavere\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Users\pavere\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\pavere\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\pavere\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\pavere\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\pavere\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\pavere\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pavere\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\pavere\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\pavere\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\pavere\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\pavere\Anaconda3\envs\test\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Any idea why this isn't working? The Python version is 3.6.10 and the conda version is 4.8.2

Answer (score 0):

In your Traceback, there are many lines with "Anaconda3" in it. Have you tried to install / reinstall Anaconda?

Answer (score 0):

Update- fixed it by downgrading to tensorflow 2.0 :)